# How to remove a placehodler if it contains another placeholder with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, placeholder

A user can enter a text and use some defined placeholders that get replaced automatically. It can happen that there is no matching value for a placeholder so that the placeholder would be replaced by an empty string or null or something like that. This could lead to useless/grammatically incorrect text.

Let's say the system provides the placeholders [Price_Difference] and [Price].
The user enters a text like *"The apple costs [Price] USD. It's now [Price_Difference] USD cheaper. Buy 7 and get 100 free."* Now we have an object in the DB which contains the price and (maybe) an old price. If an old price is defined, we can calculate the price difference, replace the placeholders and everyone is happy. But if there's no old price defined, the sentence won't make much sense.

```
$user_text = "An apple costs [Price] USD. It's now [Price_Difference] USD cheaper. Buy 7 and get 100 free.";

$usable_data = ['price' => 50, 'price_difference' => 200];
```

I could now use something like

```
$final_text = str_ireplace(
  ['[Price]', '[Price_Difference]'],
  [$usable_data['price'], $usable_data['price_difference']],
  $user_text
];
```

To get a result like *"The apple costs 50 USD. It's now 200 USD cheaper. Buy 7 and get 100 free."*

But let's assume there's an object which doesn't have an old price to calculate the price difference. The result would be something like *"The apple costs 50 USD. It's now USD cheaper. Buy 7 and get 100 free."*

My initial idea is to make parts of the text optional. Then I could replace all placeholders but only if there exists a corresponding value. In a second step I would replace all placeholders which still contain placeholders and remove the last placeholders-markers in a final step.

So as a simple example it could be something like:

```
$user_text = "An apple costs [Price] USD. [[It's now [Price_Difference] USD cheaper.]] Buy 7 and get 100 free.";

if ($usable_data['price'] > 0) {
  $final_text = str_ireplace('[Price]', $usable_data['price'], $user_text);
}

if ($usable_data['price_difference'] > 0) {
  $final_text = str_ireplace('[Price_Difference]', $usable_data['price_difference'], $user_text);
}
```

This would result in

*"An apple costs 50 USD. [[It's now [Price_Difference] USD cheaper.]] Buy 7 and get 100 free."*

Now I need something (maybe a regular expression) to find/remove all parts of the text which contains [(.*)] within [[ and ]], so the final result would be *"An apple costs 50 USD. Buy 7 and get 100 free."*

Since I got into trouble while using [ and ] both for the actual placeholder and for the "optional" parts of the text block, I started to use double [[ and ]] for the optional parts. My basically working regex is

```
$res = preg_replace("@\[\[(.*)\]\]@siU", '', $text);
```

Which actually removes successfully everything between [[ and ]]. It can't be greedy since the text can contain multiple placeholders and optional text parts. But I need something that removes that part only if there is a [ and a ] in between. So it would be something like

```
$res = preg_replace("@\[\[(.* andmusthave[and] )\]\]@siU", '', $text);
```

But I am actually in doubt that this is the best approach at all. Maybe there is something more versatile to use "optional" parts in a placeholder system?

**EDIT**

After posting this question I've got an idea, that seems to work:

```
$pr = preg_replace("@\[\[(.*)\[(.*)\](.*)\]\]@siU", '', $var);
```

But I am still not really sure if it's the best solution for the initial problem.

Comment: Consider doing something like a bbcode solution e.g. `An apple costs [Price] USD. [optional requires=Price_Difference]It's now [Price_Difference] USD cheaper.[/optional] Buy 7 and get 100 free.` then you can just use a BBCode parser/replacer with custom rules

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Not sure yet if the users will understand/accept it. But same for a [[x[y]z]] syntax :)